# Parsing Input in C revisited

Tags: c, parsing, user-input, scanf

I have an input of the form `"a b.c d.e"`(quotes excluded) I want to parse into integer values like `a1=a, a2=b, a3=c`,..and so on. But trick is the value just after `"."` can also be missing so, `"a b d.e"`, `"a b c"`, `"a b.c d"` are valid inputs. But `"a b. d.e"` isn't valid as after `"b"` there's a `"."` but no number following it. Assume the numbers ie. `"a", "b"`, etc. are integers greater than 0 and less than 1000.

I can only think about the hard way of doing it. Tried this ->

```
scanf("%d %2d[^. ].%2d[^. ] %2d[^. ].%2d[^\n]",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e);
```

but it didn't work. I appreciate any help to parse it using `scanf()` parameter trick on this.

Comment: Please chose your poison - either C or C++ - Two different languages

Comment: Should `%2d` be `%3d`?

Comment: Perhaps giving us some sample input that does not work will help

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison?

Comment: scan the full string and then try this ptr2 = strtok(ptr1," .");

Comment: Use a proper lexer and parser or a regular expression library.  Please avoid using `scanf`.

Comment: @elisa @Ed Heal doesn't work for simple input "1 2 3". (As mentioned `.` is optional.)

Comment: @elisa i can tokenize on ` ` and than on `.`,  :)

Comment: read correctly the description of strtok you can tokenize on both at the same time " .", then use ptr2 = strtok(0," ."); to find the next hit.

Comment: @Vimal Do you "*want to parse into integer values like `a1=a, a2=b, a3=c`*" from `"a b.c d.e"` or should that be `a3=d`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `a3=c` unless `c` is missing which means `.` after `b` is missing

Comment: final code -> [here](http://ideone.com/1dP0vs)  thanks all specially @elisa

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I checked your link and am a bit confused. Why have you written the code in mixed C and C++? It's fine if that's what you want, but looks a bit strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your answer to my comment, then in this case, I don't think you can shoehorn the input into a `scanf` *format string* and handle the variations you want to handle. In this case, you can however, fall back to the tried and true, parse anything, *walking a pointer down the string* with help from `strtol`.

`strtol` provides an *end-pointer* which is set to the next character after a valid conversion to `long` in the input string. Therefore, if you are working your way down a complicated input string, you start with the `strtol (p, &ep, 10)` where `p` is a pointer to your string, `ep` will be set to the next character in the string after the first number converted. (in your case either a `'.'` or `' '`). If the next character is a `'.'`, you can preform further tests on the character that follows and make a determination of whether your input string is valid or not as you collect the values one-by-one.

After you test the needed conditions and advance `ep` to point to the beginning of the next valid number to convert, you simply set `p = ep;` and repeat until you have filled `a, b & c` or hit an error condition.

When using `strtol` there are several additional validations you can use beyond checking `errno`, but that will suffice for this example. See `man strtol` for the remaining validations.

If I have your logic correctly understood, you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXC 32

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "", *p = buf, *ep = NULL;
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, tmp = 0;

    printf ("enter values: ");
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin))
        return 1;

    for (;;) {
        tmp = strtol (p, &ep, 10);
        if (errno) {    /* minimal conversion validation */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: failed conversion.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (!a)         /* handle a */
            a = tmp;
        else if (!b) {  /* handle b */
            if (*ep && *ep == '.' && *(ep + 1) &&  *(ep + 1) == ' ') {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input = '.' alone.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            b = tmp;
            if (*ep && *ep == '.' && *(ep + 1) && 
                '0' <= *(ep + 1) && *(ep + 1) <= '9')
                ep++;
            else
                while (*ep && (*ep < '0' || '9' < *ep))
                    ep++;
            if (!*ep) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - no 'c'.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else if (!c) {  /* handle c */
            if (*ep && *ep == '.' && *(ep + 1) && 
                (*(ep + 1) == ' ' || *(ep + 1) == '\n')) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input = '.' alone.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            c = tmp;
            break;
        }
        p = ep;
    }

    printf ("a : %d\nb : %d\nc : %d\n", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/triplet
enter values: 1 2.3 4.5
a : 1
b : 2
c : 3

$ ./bin/triplet
enter values: 1 2 3.4
a : 1
b : 2
c : 3

$ ./bin/triplet
enter values: 1 2 3
a : 1
b : 2
c : 3

$ ./bin/triplet
enter values: 1 2.3 4
a : 1
b : 2
c : 3

$ ./bin/triplet
enter values: 1 2. 3.4
error: invalid input = '.' alone.
```

Look things over and let me know if I misunderstood your comment. If not, always remember you can parse anything by simply *walking a pointer (or pair of pointers) down the string*.

Comment: You test for failed conversion is incomplete: you should check if th long value exceeds the range of `int` and if `ep > p`.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I explicitly noted `/* minimal conversion validation */` in the code itself and explained *"When using `strtol` there are several additional validations you can use beyond checking `errno`,"* in the answer itself referencing `man strtol` for the remaining validations, e.g. `ERANGE` and `(tmp == LONG_MIN || tmp == LONG_MAX)` for *overflow* or `p == ep` for *no digits*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to use `scanf()` for your purpose.  If you want strict validation of the input, you must write a tailored parser.

Here is a solution:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *skipblanks(char *p) {
    while (isblank((unsigned char)*p)
        p++;
    return p;
}

int getnumber(char *p, char **pp, int *dest) {
    if (strchr("0123456789+-", *p) {
        long val;
        errno = 0;
        val = strtol(p, pp, 10);
        if (errno == 0 && *pp > p && val >= INT_MIN && val <= INT_MAX) {
            *dest = val;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int parseinput(char *p, int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *e)) {
    return getnumber(p, &p, a)
       &&  (*p != '.' || getnumber(p + 1, &p, b))
       &&  isblank((unsigned char)*p)
       &&  getnumber(skipblanks(p), &p, c))
       &&  (*p != '.' || getnumber(p + 1, &p, d))
       &&  isblank((unsigned char)*p)
       &&  getnumber(skipblanks(p), &p, e))
       &&  *skipblanks(p) == '\n';
}

int main(void) {
    char buf[128];
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    int status;
    char *p;

    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        /* set default values for b and d */
        a = b = c = d = e = 0;
        if (parseinput(buf, &a, &b, &c, &d, &e)) {
            printf("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d, d=%d, e=%d\n, a, b, c, d, e);
        } else {
            printf("input format error\n");
        }
    } else {
       printf("no input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```